# Get the first value from map using expression

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-1.2

I am trying to get the first value of a map by following

```
TreeMap<String, String> myMap = new TreeMap<String, String>();
myMap.put("key1","value1");
myMap.put("key2","value2");
String first = myMap.firstEntry().getValue();
String firstOther = myMap.get(myMap.firstKey());
```

its working for me writing in `Java`

In same  i am using expression in `jsf` like following

```
${criterion.variableBindings.firstEntry.getValue()}
```

In this scenario I didn't get the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please # for the calling method or variable of a bean class..

```
#{criterion.variableBindings.firstEntry.getValue()}
```

If you didn't get for for above

create a variable inside bean class setter and getter then access that variable in jsf file.

In bean

```
 private String  first ;  
 first = myMap.firstEntry().getValue();
 //setterand getter
```

in jsp

```
#{bean.first}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to invoke the **method** firstEntry, so you need to use method invocation syntax, which has parentheses after the method name:

```
${criterion.variableBindings.firstEntry().getValue()}
```

If the method had been named `getFirstEntry` you could have accessed it as a property as well, but since it does not start with `get` you need to access it as a method.